# How do I search Instagram's api for emojis

Tags: web-applications, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to make a call like

```
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$tag.'/media/recent?client_id='.$client_id;
```

but where the `$tag` is I want to pass in an emoji in order to get results back for emojis. I've tried .....

`$tag = 'U+1F601';`

`$tag = '\xF0\x9F\x98\x81';`

`$tag = '\x{1F601}';`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a query like
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%8C/media/recent?client_id=`

where `%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%8C` is an urlencode word (or emoji).

For the example this is an utf-8 encoding word.
So you should add

```
$tag=urlencode($tag);
```

before query. And `$tag` should be in right encoding.